# res.status is not a fumction

Tags: typescript, next.js, google-api

I am working on connecting my next app with google sheets, this is the function that handles the post request and I moved it to the following location "app/api/sheets" as the documentation suggest I should

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { google } from 'googleapis'


type SheetForm = {
    name: string,
    city: string,
    phone: string
}

export async function POST(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
){
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(405).send({ message: "Only POST requests are allowed"})
    }
    
    const body = req.body as SheetForm

    try {
        //prepare authentication
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            credentials: {
                client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
                private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\n/g, '\n')
            },
            scopes: [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
            ]
        });

        const sheets = google.sheets({
            auth,
            version: 'v4'
        });

        const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: process.env.GOOGLE_SHEET_ID,
            range: 'Trabajo!A2:C',
            valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
            requestBody: {
                values: [
                    [body.name, body.city, body.phone]
                ]
            }
        });

        return res.status(200).json({
            data: response.data
        })

    }catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message ?? "Something went wrong" });
    }

}
```

And this is how I am fetching the API

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [city, setCity] = useState('')
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = {
      name,
      city,
      phone
    }

    const response = await fetch('/api/sheets', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(form)
    })

    const content = await response.json();

    console.log(content);
    alert(content.data.tableRange);

    setName('')
    setCity('')
    setPhone('')
  }
```

This gives me the following error "⨯ TypeError: res.status is not a function
at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/sheets/route.ts:48:20)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In next you it works in a little bit different than express.
Since your method is named as `POST`, Next will handle the method allowance for you (you dont need to return 405).

When you return the response, the ideal way is to use `NextResponse`

```
return NextResponse.json(payload, { status: 200, statusText: 'OK' });
```

If you would like to return Http OK, then you can skip the second parameter, because it will fall back to that by default.

Comment: So instead of using my res attribute i just return a NextResponse  instead? also what is payload?